# Convert sf::st polygon into raster

Tags: raster, r, sf

I have WGS84 coordinates that form a closed polygon. I need to turn this polygon into a raster, but the different solutions to similar questions I found don't work for some reason I don't understand. I'm using `st_polygon` from the `sf` package because I also need to buffer my polygon before rasterizing.

```
cords<-structure(list(Long = c(-156.561080555555, -156.598241666666, -156.703805555555, 
-156.656733333333, -156.561080555555), Lat = c(20.7502555555555, 
20.7919527777777, 20.7545472222222, 20.7300472222222, 20.7502555555555
)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), class = "data.frame")

require(sf)
poly<-st_polygon(list(as.matrix(cords)))
buffer<-st_buffer(poly,0.02)
poly_buffered<-st_union(poly,buffer)
```

This is where I'm stuck. I tried

```
require(raster)
require(fasterize)
template <- raster(poly_buffered, 0.02)
poly_raster <- fasterize(poly_buffered, template)
```

but that throws an error in the `raster()` call:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"XY"’
```

I also tried `rasterize(poly_buffered, 0.02)` and get the same error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘rasterize’ for signature ‘"XY", "numeric"’
```

Comment: That error says its in a call to `rasterize`, not `raster`, and you don't seem to have called `rasterize` (which is a function in the raster package). Also, there's a double `<-<-` in `poly_buffered<-<-st_union(poly,buffer)` which doesn't work and makes me think you've not pasted your code completely. The problem you are getting is going to be related to some functions accepting old "Spatial" objects and you constructing new "sf" objects which aren't compatible. If you can make a complete copy-paste example with the correct error message (and you are 90% there) I'll get on it.

Comment: The double ```<-<-``` seems to have been a copy&paste error that I don't know where it stems from between my code and here. I edited my post. The ```st_``` calls work and I can plot them without problems, so that is not where the problem stems. I checked my code and noticed I tried both ```raster()``` and ```rasterize()``` and copied the wrong error message; I edited my post accordingly. Open to alternative approaches as long as I can get a raster out of it from my input coordinates + buffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this these days is without using the `raster` package and using the `terra` package instead.

This uses its own data type for polygons, so you need to convert them using the function `vect` when you use them. Here:

```
template = rast(vect(poly_buffered),res=0.005)
```

You can then use `rasterize`:

```
poly_raster <- rasterize(vect(poly_buffered), template)
plot(poly_raster,col="red")
```

[image]

If you want to use `fasterize` then you have to convert your `sf` polygon to an `sf` spatial polygon data frame which can be done with a call to `st_as_sf` and `data.frame` and `st_sfc` (but there might be better ways) and you have to convert your `terra` raster template to a `raster` package one because `fasterize` only likes raster objects from the `raster` package:

```
poly_raster <- fasterize(st_as_sf(data.frame(geometry=st_sfc(poly_buffered))), raster::raster(template))
plot(poly_raster)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked great! I've admittedly been overwhelmed by the various spatial analysis packages and formats and I think that was part of the reason why I couldn't get it to work. Really appreciated!